# Hubot greet @username when logged in to chatroom

Tags: github, coffeescript, hubot

Hubot is a great tool, The robot is integrated in our chat rooms and deploys several tasks. A couple of extras features have been added to hubot such and greet when commanded. I am not very good with coffee script and currently would like to find a way for Hubot to greet users who log into chatrooms accordingly to the time  in the day`(@uersname Good morning, @username Good Afternoon, etc.)`

A simple Hello created:

```
# hubot greeting.
#
# (hi|hello) - say hi to your butler

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /hi|hello/i, (msg) ->
    msg.send "Howdy!"
```

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: "Howdy", perhaps too informal, it is a robot assistant not a gun slinger

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure about a way to get users handles but there is an event robot.enter

```
    robot.enter (response) ->
      msg.send "Welcome, Lord #{response.message.user.name}"
```